# centos, нехватка места

Tags: linux, centos

Здравствуйте, есть сервер на centos, все хорошо но начал выдавать ошибки. После быстрого анализа, определил что проблема в наличии свободного места. Я как порядочный человек, удалил старые бекапы, логи, почистил мусор, сессии и тд. Сайты заработали, все ок, НО! После проверок через du и df получил такую картину.

```
[root@vps-17622 ~]# du -sh /*
12K /aquota.group
12K /aquota.user
5,9M    /bin
65M /boot
4,0K    /cgroup
148K    /dev
31M /etc
4,0K    /home
336M    /lib
20K /lost+found
4,0K    /media
4,0K    /mnt
142M    /opt
0   /proc
104K    /root
8,6M    /sbin
4,0K    /selinux
4,0K    /srv
0   /sys
128K    /tmp
1,2G    /usr
30G /var
[root@vps-17622 ~]# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda3     3726848 499840 3227008   14% /
tmpfs           181587      1  181586    1% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       51200     50   51150    1% /boot
[root@vps-17622 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda3       58G   54G  897M  99% /
tmpfs           2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      194M   71M  114M  39% /boot
```

И вот вопрос, почему на проверке через df я вижу только 1% свободного места, ведь если верить du, у меня 25-26гб свободного места (всего 60гб), а это 45%? С centos и в частности с yum я не очень дружу, привык к debian

Comment: Ключ `-i` команды `df` выдает _количество занятых инодов_, а не количество занятых блоков. Т.е. он выдает количество созданных на файловой системе файлов (грубо говоря, инод все таки не совсем файл, но очень близко) в сравнении с максимальным количеством инодов на ФС. К занимаемому объему эта цифра никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: @Mike там есть второй вывод df со всеми данными

Comment: там в самом низу есть еще `df -h`

Comment: @ArtemBelash Это я вижу, я пока про -i сказал, что его смотреть нет смысла ... Про остальное пока не ясно. Вернее я подозреваю, что du берет размеры файлов, а это совершенно не то же самое, что занимаемое место на диске. Т.е. не учитывается, что файл длиной 1 байт на самом деле занимает целый блок (не менее 4Кб). но это все равно не объясняет такую большую разницу. Я бы конечно заподозрил, что у вас на корню есть какие то каталоги с именами на точку и в них большие файлы, но я в этом сильно сомневаюсь, ибо обычно таких каталогов на корне не бывает

Comment: Так, стоп... Вы когда логи удаляли после этого syslog и другие программы, которые писали те логи, перезапускали ? Ведь если в системе у процессов остались открытыми файлы, которые вы удалили, то место на диске не освободится, пока они их не закроют. при этом du этих файлов в каталогах уже не увидит ...

Comment: точно, не перезапускал, спасибо вам добрый человек)

Comment: `[root@vps-17622 ~]# service rsyslog restart
Shutting down system logger:                               [  OK  ]
Starting system logger:                                    [  OK  ]
[root@vps-17622 ~]# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda3      59774204 55431336   1307404  98% /
tmpfs            2002600        0   2002600   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1        198337    71825    116272  39% /boot` в общем ситуация не изменилась, занято 98%. Ночью ребутну серв, если будет результат - отпишусь

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, после ребута nginx и httpd все стало на свои места

Comment: [возможный дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521346/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin что ж так скромно, даже не проголосовали за дубликат?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, потому что я уже голосовал за закрытие, но по другой причине. а потом вспомнил, что был же подобный вопрос. найдя его, с удивлением обнаружил, что я же на него и отвечал.