# Как освободить занятое место в Proxmox?

Tags: linux, debian, lxc, proxmox

У меня контейнер под Proxmox. После удаления в нём большого файла размером 14 гигабайт. Объём свободного места в Proxmox разделе остался на уровне 13 процентов. Как очистить свободное место после удаления файла?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521368/178576